# tensorflow2 model.fit error - how can I fix this error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have been working on converting vector data into images. The image size is a 6x6 grayscale image. And I'm making a model for classifying 6x6 grayscale images using tensorflow on google colab.

Here is an image sample(very small size image):
[image]

However, when the model.fit() function is called, the following error message occurs in epoch 1.

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance for the reply.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop


base_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/sample_img'

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')

train_normal_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'normal')
train_attack_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'attack')

test_normal_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'normal')
test_attack_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'attack')

train_normal_fnames = os.listdir(train_normal_dir)
train_attack_fnames = os.listdir(train_attack_dir)

# Create Model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(6,6,1), padding='same'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.summary()

# Compile Model

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),
            loss='binary_crossentropy',
            metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Data Preprocessing

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )
test_datagen  = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                  batch_size=20,
                                                  class_mode='binary',
                                                  target_size=(6, 6))
validation_generator =  test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                                                       batch_size=20,
                                                       class_mode  = 'binary',
                                                       target_size = (6, 6))

# Model Fitting
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=100,
                    epochs=100,
                    validation_steps=50,
                    verbose=2)
```

Error Message

```
Epoch 1/100

NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-fc43f60c1de5> in <module>()
      4                     epochs=100,
      5                     validation_steps=50,
----> 6                     verbose=2)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

NotFoundError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential_8/conv2d_16/Conv2D' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
      handler_func(fileobj, events)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 577, in _handle_events
      self._handle_recv()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 606, in _handle_recv
      self._run_callback(callback, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
      callback(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
      return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
      handler(stream, idents, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
      if self.run_code(code, result):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-40-fc43f60c1de5>", line 6, in <module>
      verbose=2)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 452, in call
      inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 589, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 248, in call
      outputs = self.convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 240, in convolution_op
      name=self.__class__.__name__)
Node: 'sequential_8/conv2d_16/Conv2D'
No algorithm worked!  Error messages:
     [[{{node sequential_8/conv2d_16/Conv2D}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2706]
```

Comment: The error seems to be in the first layer of your model, have you tried to change it to `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')`

Comment: @Cardstdani I've tried, but it doesn't work. Without input_size, the model cannot be created.